# apache shiro filter authc and user in the case /**

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

Here is part of my code.

```java
...
Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/favicon.ico", "anon");
filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/css/**", "anon");
filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/js/**", "anon");

filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/logout", "logout");

filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "authc");
...
```

I set `/**` as `authc` at the end of my filter chain, but when I try to access `ip:port/favicon.ico`, it redirects me to `/login` page. All the previous `anon` definitions don't work.

However when I just change `/**` to `user`, everything works well now.

```java
filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "user");
```

> dependencies

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Comment: Do you have sample project (on GitHub?) we can take a look at.  What other spring dependencies do you have?

Comment: @Brian Demers  [Link to the full code example](https://github.com/zymint/shiro-example)

Answer (score 0):

This was left out of your question, and is the cause of the issue.
https://github.com/zymint/shiro-example/blob/master/tp/src/main/java/tp/softfly/config/shiro/ShiroConfig.java#L25-L27

The form filter only needs to be used for your /login route.  Not custom defined for all your routes.  Removing these lines resolves the problem